# How to Change Opacity of Selected background color of View using UISlider?

Tags: swift, uislider

I want to create custom colour picker according to my requirement.
I do not want to go with third party.
How can I increase or decrease the opacity of particular when slider value is changed?

screenshot is below:

[image: Slider demo in xcode]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you set up your slider and create a connection to the value change like so....

[image]

Then change the minimum and maximum values of the slider to 0 to 1

then implement this inside your sliderValueChanged handler

```
@IBAction func sliderValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
     var currentValue = Int(sender.value)

     self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: sender.value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own Answer.

```
    let currentValue = CGFloat(sender.value)
    self.tvView.backgroundColor = tvView.textColor?.colorWithAlphaComponent(currentValue)
```